# Drawing signal-time plots using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a large number of plots like this. Is there any tikz package that I can use, instead of drawing each from scratch?
This is the code I wrote for the first picture, but I can't get the label position right. 
Also, I don't need the ticks on the y axis.

I will need to change the width of the rectangle, the numbers marked on the horizontal axis and the y axis label on each plot

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=6cm,
height=6cm,
x axis line style={-stealth},
y axis line style={-stealth},
xtick={-2,2},
xmin=-3, ymin=-3,
ymax = 3, xmax=3,
axis lines*=center,
xlabel={Time,t $\rightarrow$},
ylabel={x(t)},
]
\addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot]
coordinates
{(-2,0) (-2,1) (2,1) (2,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Signal- time plotes]

Comment: Are you able to post compilable code, at least for one of the plots, this will give a better idea of what you want and make it easier for people to answer your question.  Your current specification is also quite loose, should the plots be equal volume or equal height, or something more variable for example?

Comment: @DaiBowen I am working on the compilable code, but I am quite new to tikz and really not getting anything right. The plots can vary in height as well as volume. The general shape is like that in the pictures

Comment: @DaiBowen I have posted the code

Comment: lexxie, do you want something [like this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ihveJ.png)?  You should clarify what parameters do you expect to change in each plot (considering all the plots, not just these ones!), and add that to your question.

Comment: If you are repeating the same parameters, like [x axis line style={-stealth}], you can set them as defaults using \pgfkeys, \tikzset or \pgfplotsset.

Comment: @Alenanno Those are exactly the kind of figures I need!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the plots are not going to be more complicated than this, you can use Tikz. However keep in mind that this solution only takes into account the details you have shared in this question and therefore the code might need some changes if there are more parameters that should be included.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand\sgraph[2][]{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\rig{abs{#2}}
\tikz{%
\draw[thick, -Latex] (0,-1) node[below] {Time, $t \rightarrow$} -- (0,3) node[right] {$x(#1t)$};
\draw[thick, -Latex] ({#2-1},0) -- ({\rig+1},0);
\node[anchor=north west] at (0,0) {$0$};
\draw (#2,-.2) node[below] {$#2$} |- (\rig,1) -- (\rig,-.2) node[below] {$\rig$};
}
}

\begin{document}
\sgraph{-2}
\sgraph[\alpha]{-1}
\sgraph[\gamma]{-4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Along the same lines, here is how I tackled the unsymmetrical boxes     \newcommand\unsgraph[3][]{%
\tikz{%
\draw[thick, -Latex] (0,-1) node[below] {Time, $t \rightarrow$} -- (0,3) node[right] {$x(#1t)$};
\draw[thick, -Latex] ({#2-1},0) -- ({#3+1},0);
\node[anchor=north west] at (0,0) {$0$};
\draw (#2,-.2) node[below] {$#2$} |- (#3,1) -- (#3,-.2) node[below] {$#3$};
}
}

Answer (score 4):

Moving defaults to \pgfplotsset:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={
  width=6cm,
  height=6cm,
  axis lines*=center,
  x axis line style={-stealth},
  y axis line style={-stealth},
  tick align=center,
  xlabel={Time,t $\rightarrow$},
  ylabel={x(t)},
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-3, ymin=-3,
ymax = 3, xmax=3,
]
\addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot]
coordinates
{(-2,0) (-2,1) (2,1) (2,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As supplement to John Kormylo answer (slightly changed):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13,
width=5cm,
xmin=-5,xmax=5,
ymax=2.5,
axis lines*=center,
axis line style={-stealth},
ytick=\empty,
x tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
xlabel={$t$},
xlabel style={at={(1,0.1)},right},
ylabel style={at={(0.5,1)},below right,rotate=-90},
            }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel={$x(t)$}]
\addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot] coordinates
    {(-2,0) (-2,1) (2,1) (2,0)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel={$x(\alpha t)$}]
\addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot] coordinates
    {(-1,0) (-1,1) (1,1) (1,0)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel={$x(\gamma t)$}]
\addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot] coordinates
    {(-4,0) (-4,1) (4,1) (4,0)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would instead define a function once and use it throughout by manipulating the samples or if compile time is not an issue simply increasing the sample size to get verticals right.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={% heaviside(var,left limit,right limit. amplitude)
  heaviside(\x,\l,\r,\a)=max( 0 , ( \x>= \l ?(\x> \r?0:\a):0);
  } 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines*=center,
  axis line style={-stealth},
]
  \addplot+[thick,no marks,samples at={-5,-4.01,-4,2,2.01,3}]{heaviside(x,-4,2,5)};
  \addplot+[thick,no marks,samples at={-5,-1.01,-1,1,1.01,3}]{heaviside(x,-1,1,1)};
  \addplot+[thick,no marks,samples at={-5,-2.01,-2,3,3.01,4}]{heaviside(x,-2,3,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]